# Unable to replace CustomToolbar with ActionBar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-viewbinding

I Created a Custom `Toolbar` and placed it in activity, but I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.citiesdistance.feature.main.MainActivity@3a04806 does not have an ActionBar set via setSupportActionBar()
```

**Note :**

When I set the default `ActionBar` to show The Custom `Toolbar` work correctly, but it is under the default `ActionBar`.

**CustomToolbar Class :**

```
class BaseToolbar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
    private lateinit var binding: ViewToolbarBinding

    init {
        if (attrs != null) {
            binding = ViewToolbarBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
            val attr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BaseToolbar)
            val title = attr.getString(R.styleable.BaseToolbar_bs_title)
            if (!title.isNullOrEmpty())
                binding.toolbarTitleTv.text = title
            attr.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

**view_toolbar.xml (CustomToolbar Xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        style="?textAppearanceHeadline6"
        tools:text="نام صفحه"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/WidthHeight.All.BothMatchParent"
    tools:context=".feature.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.example.view.BaseToolbar
            android:id="@+id/testToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:bs_title="Page 1" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**themes.xml :**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.CitiesDistance" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        .
        .
        .
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Default ActionBar :**

[image]

**NoActionBar :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only step you are missing is the step 5 from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/appbar/setting-up

> In the activity's onCreate() method, call the activity's setSupportActionBar() method, and pass the activity's toolbar.

Comment: setSupportActionBar() require a ToolBar but my CustomToolbar class extends FrameLayout

Comment: You can define custom layout inside the Toolbar - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-toolbar-xml-layout-kotlin#android-custom-toolbar

Comment: I need this class for dependency injection

Comment: Why exactly do you need it to inherit from FrameLayout? Maybe it can inherit from Toolbar instead (which is also ViewGroup)...

Comment: I want to add extra items only for some specific activities in toolbar and I can do it with FrameLayout. also, this is the best way as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I set default `ActionBar` with DarkActionBar then add `supportActionBar?.hide()` in Activity's onCreate method.
I will update answer If I find a better sulotion.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.CitiesDistance" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        .
        .
        .
    </style>
</resources>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
}
```